# Windbg disassembler address resolution

Tags: windbg, disassembly

I was analysing a complete memory dump and I applied Windbg `uf` command to see what a function does

```
0: kd> uf profsvc!CUserProfileService::_RegisterGPNotification
```

This is the part of the output. I wonder why the address in parentheses is different than the address  of `profsvc!CUserProfileService::_RegisterGPNotification+0x44` which should be

`000007fe fb149276`

but is

`000007fe fb155019`.

When I try to unassembled the address `000007fe fb155019` with `u` it points to

`profsvc!CUserProfileService::_RegisterGPNotification+0x44:`

I’m really puzzled, any help deeply appreciated.

OUTPUT from WinDBG

```
….
profsvc!CUserProfileService::_RegisterGPNotification+0x2e:
000007fe`fb14925e ba01000000      mov     edx,1
000007fe`fb149263 488bc8          mov     rcx,rax
000007fe`fb149266 ff157c410200    call    qword ptr [profsvc!_imp_RegisterGPNotification (000007fe`fb16d3e8)]
000007fe`fb14926c 85c0            test    eax,eax
000007fe`fb14926e 0f84a5bd0000    je      profsvc!CUserProfileService::_RegisterGPNotification+0x44 (**000007fe`fb155019**)

profsvc!CUserProfileService::_RegisterGPNotification+0x40:
000007fe`fb149274 33db            xor     ebx,ebx
000007fe`fb149276 eb00            jmp     profsvc!CUserProfileService::_RegisterGPNotification+0x66 (000007fe`fb149278)  Branch

profsvc!CUserProfileService::_RegisterGPNotification+0x66:
000007fe`fb149278 488b0d31b00200  mov     rcx,qword ptr [profsvc!WPP_GLOBAL_Control (000007fe`fb1742b0)]
000007fe`fb14927f 488d052ab00200  lea     rax,[profsvc!WPP_GLOBAL_Control (000007fe`fb1742b0)]
000007fe`fb149286 483bc8          cmp     rcx,rax
000007fe`fb149289 740a            je      profsvc!CUserProfileService::_RegisterGPNotification+0x94 (000007fe`fb149295)  Branch

0: kd> u 000007fe`fb155019
profsvc!CUserProfileService::_RegisterGPNotification+0x44:
000007fe`fb155019 ??              ???
                         ^ Memory access error in 'u 000007fe`fb155019'
```

Comment: There could be a valid question in here somewhere but this is unreadable. *I wonder why the address in parentheses* What parentheses do you mean?

Comment: I meant the parentheses below at the instruction je profsvc!CUserProfileService::_RegisterGPNotification+0x44 (**000007fe`fb155019**). Normally je jumps to profsvc!CUserProfileService::_RegisterGPNotification+0x44 which is not the address 000007fe`fb155019 why address is differnt than the jumping address? Thanks for the help.

Comment: optimized disassembly does not match with offset shown in symbols linearly   after optimization functions can be broken into chunks  and the pdb does not reflect the optimized Address (windbg can usually resolve it even if they are not linear )    the address in brackets that are called  $ea and $ea2 pseudo registers will always be rigt

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to optimization, see the following MSDN article:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541382(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate it.